# How I can plot a expected richness curve (Chao1) via vegan in R

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I have a dataset from one site containing data on species and its abundance (number of individuals for each species in sample).
I use vegan package for alpha diversity analysis.
For instance, I plot a species rarefraction curve via rarecurve function (I cann't use a specaccum function becouse I have data from one site), and calculate a Chao1 index via estimateR function.

How I can plot a Chao1 expected richness curve using estimateR function? Then, I would like to combine these curves on one single plot.

```
library(vegan)
TR <- matrix(nrow=1,c(3,1,1,17,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,13,31,24,6,1,1,4,1,10,2,3,1,5,6,1,1,1,4,16,17,15,6,9,66,3,1,3,24,15,2,3,17,1,7,2,27,13,2,1,1,3,1,3,30,7,1,1,4,1,2,5,1,1,6,2,1,9,11,5,8,7,2,2,2,1,13,3,8,4,1,5,27,1,62,13,6,7,7,4,9,1,7,7,1,25,1,5,3,1,2,1,1,5,2,73,25,17,43,88,2,3,38,4,5,6,6,16,2,13,10,7,1,2,9,3,1,3,1,8,4,4,5,13,2,25,9,2,1,12,29,4,1,9,1,1,3,4,2,9,4,26,2,7,4,18,1,10,10,4,6,5,20,1,2,11,1,3,1,2,1,1,12,3,2,1,4,24,7,22,19,43,2,9,18,1,1,1,9,7,6,1,8,2,2,19,7,26,4,4,1,3,4,5,2,4,8,2,3,1,5,5,1,11,6,6,2,4,3,1,10,6,9,16,1,1,32,1,1,31,2,12,2,13,1,2,9,13,1,11,8,1,14,5,9,1,3,1,7,1,1,13,17,1,1,3,2,9,1,4,1,7,2,2,9,24,20,2,1,2,2,1,9,5,1,1,23,13,7,1,8,5,47,32,6,13,16,8,2,1,5,4,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,14,6,21,2,7,2,2,16,2,10,21,18,2,1,3,33,12,55,4,1,5,14,3,10,2,4,1,2,5,7,6,2,12,14,28,18,30,28,7,1,1,1,3,4,2,17,60,31,3,3,2,2,3,6,2,6,1,13,2,3,13,7,2,10,19,9,7,1,3))
num_species=specnumber(TR)
chao1=estimateR(TR)[2,]
shannon=diversity(TR,"shannon")
rarecurve(TR)
estimateR(TR)
```

Here is a plot, building on EstimateS output (I input the same data) with SigmaPlot:

[image: Individual-based species accumulation curve (SAC) (thick line) and the Chao 1 estimator (thin line) of expected richness;]

Thin line is expected richness - Chao1. In R I can plot only SAC.
In EstimateS I get a set with data for all 2990 individuals, but not in R.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Off-site links are not preferred. You can simply edit your question to include `sp_data <- matrix(nrow=1,c(3,1,1,17,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,13,31,24,6,1,1,4,1,10,2,3,1,5,6,1,1,1, 4,16,17,15,6,9,66,3,1,3,24,15,2,3,17,1,7,2,27,13,2,1,1,3,1,3,30,7, 1,1,4,1,2,5,1,1,6,2,1,9,11,5,8,7,2,2,2,1,13,3,8,4,1,5,27,1,62,13,6, 7,7,4,9,1,7,7,1,25,1,5))` (I picked the first 100 species from your data).

Comment: can you define / point to a definition of a "Chao1 estimate curve"?

Comment: Do you mean you want to `rrarefy` (hint) your one site and get the Chao-1 for each of the randomly rarefied (hint) sub-sample size?

Comment: You should never say "I can get it .... but not in R": there is no such thing as not getting something in R. There may be a thing of how to get it, but surely you get it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how things are done in **estimateS**, but it looks like the extended richness (Chao 1) curve is based on the mean of random subsamples of the community. This could be done like this:

```
subchao <- sapply(1:2990, function(i) 
   mean(sapply(1:100, function(...) estimateR(rrarefy(TR, i))[2,])))
```

This would randomly rarefy (`rrarefy()`) to all sample sizes from 1 to 2990 and find the mean from 100 replicates of each. This will take time.